# Receiving widget callback inside cell execution

Tags: jupyter

Is there any way of allowing widget state update messages from javascript to python side through during Jupyter cell execution?

We're having a DOMWidget dipslaying a webpage with an API for communication over Http messages. So we manage to send commands and get back the response to the javascript side of the widget. The problem is that the widget state update isn't received on the python side until after the Jupyter cell has finished it's execution. I guess this is because the kernel is busy with the cell execution and receive functions is put on que.

The workaround for now is that the response is written to a synced traitlet from the javascript side which the user can access in a subsequent cell. We also display a output widget with text linked to a another traitlet to give information when the response is received. This is a bit messy and I would like to have more control over the execution to wait with subsequent cell executions until the response is received or timeout.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct way to make Jupyter code cells wait for an event or value sent from a widget.  The problem is that the (Python) kernel only sends one-way messages to the (Javascript) widget and there is no way to make the kernel wait for a response from the Javascript side.

Python code can intercept callbacks invoked by Javascript in various ways but the results of those callbacks will not show up in cell output in the usual way.  They must be stored in the Kernel state or displayed in a widget context -- see the Output standard widget, for example.

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html

You can use the output widget to display results sent from the Javascript implementation of a widget, but the output shows up in the widget context, not as the usual cell output.

For example the following strategy won't work if the user does a "run all"

- Cell 1 creates a widget which interacts with the user and calls back to
  Python to create a file "./xxx.dat" in the filesystem.
- Cell 2 enters an infinite polling loop waiting for "./xxx.dat" to appear
  before proceeding.

If the user interactively runs the cells one at a time this might work.
But in the present implementation of Jupyter widgets if the user does "run all"
the infinite loop in "Cell 2" must start and complete before the widget in "Cell 1" is
created and since the loop never completes the widget will never get created
and the file will never appear and the notebook will be frozen.

Also please see the jp_proxy_widget tutorial for more discussion of
the asynchronous nature of Jupyter widgets.

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget/blob/master/notebooks/Tutorial.ipynb